# Putting divs side by side

Tags: html, css, css-float

I cannot put related-video div near to the iframe. Here is a [demo](http://www.cruisear.com/test/test1.html) I have added `float:left` to the iframe but it hasn't worked. How can i put related videos to right side of the iframe like image below?

[image: what i want]

Comment: Please, don't answer a closed question by editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this.,

```
#related-videos {
    float: left;
}
```